# Netlogo, distribution and driving lanes in roundabouts

Tags: netlogo

[

```html
globals [ gl_my-car gl_cars-count gl_accelerator gl_decelerator gl_speed-max gl_speed-min gl_speed-maxcircle gl_speed-maxright gl_distance-straight 
gl_distance-left gl_distance-right gl_degree-per-foot gl_side gl_slowdown gl_straightdistance 
gl_distanceto00 gl_carminseparation gl_reactiontime
  gl_motospeed-max gl_my-moto gl_moto-count
  gl_truckspeed-max gl_my-truck gl_truck-count
  gl_busspeed-max gl_my-bus gl_bus-count
  gl_motominseparation  gl_truckminseparation  gl_busminseparation 
  ]

breed [cartop car]
breed [mototopview moto] 
breed [trucktopview truck]
breed [bustopview bus]
turtles-own [ 
  speed droundabout headingdirection 
  lane
  ]

to setup
clear-all

set gl_cars-count 0
; 100 ticks per second
set gl_moto-count 0
set gl_truck-count 0
set gl_bus-count 0
set gl_accelerator 0.001 ; 10 ft per second per second
set gl_decelerator 0.001 ; 10 ft per second per second
set gl_speed-max 0.5133333333333 ; 35mph, 51.3333 ft per second
set gl_speed-min 1.e-10
set gl_speed-maxcircle gl_speed-max * 0.5 ; half normal speed
set gl_speed-maxright gl_speed-max * 0.62 ; about 60% normal speed
set gl_distance-straight 34.77
set gl_distance-left 58.34
set gl_distance-right 35.2
set gl_degree-per-foot 3.81972
set gl_side sqrt (15 ^ 2 - 6 ^ 2)
set gl_slowdown (gl_speed-max ^ 2 - gl_speed-maxcircle ^ 2) / (2 * (gl_decelerator))
set gl_straightdistance gl_slowdown + gl_side
set gl_distanceto00 sqrt (gl_straightdistance ^ 2 + 6 ^ 2)
set gl_carminseparation 15; assume car lenght 10' & distance between cars 5'
set gl_motominseparation 10
set gl_truckminseparation 20
set gl_busminseparation 25
set gl_reactiontime 100; 100 ticks or 1 second reaction time

;;;tao xe oto
create-cartop NumberCartop
[
  set color (random 3 * 40 + 15) ; 15=red=go right, 55=green=go straight, 95=sky=go left
  set shape "car top"
  set size 5
  set speed gl_speed-max - random-float .1 ;;thhiet lap hinh dang xe và bao cao vi tri
  set droundabout 0
  set headingdirection 0
  distribute-cars
]

;;;;tao xe may
create-mototopview Numbermotos
   [
     set color (random 3 * 40 + 15 )
     set shape "motortopview"
     set size 3
     set speed gl_motospeed-max - random-float .1 ;;thhiet lap hinh dang xe và bao cao vi tri
     set droundabout 0
     set headingdirection 0
     distribute-motos
   ]

;;; tao xe tai
create-trucktopview Numbertruck
   [
     set color (random 3 * 40 + 15 )
     set shape "trucktopview"
     set size 7
     set speed gl_truckspeed-max - random-float .1 ;;thhiet lap hinh dang xe và bao cao vi tri
     set droundabout 0
     set headingdirection 0
     distribute-truck
   ]
   
  ;; tao xe bus
  create-bustopview Numberbus
   [
     set color (random 3 * 40 + 15 )
     set shape "bustopview"
     set size 7
     set speed gl_busspeed-max - random-float .1 ;;thhiet lap hinh dang xe và bao cao vi tri
     set droundabout 0
     set headingdirection 0
     distribute-bus
   ]
set gl_my-car one-of cartop
watch gl_my-car
set gl_my-moto one-of mototopview
watch gl_my-moto 
set gl_my-truck one-of trucktopview
watch gl_my-truck 
set gl_my-bus one-of bustopview
watch gl_my-bus 
ask patches 
[
  ;;;tao vong xuyen
     if (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 < 35 ^ 2) and (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 > 10 ^ 2)
    [
     set pcolor grey
    ]
    ;;;;tao cay xanh trong vong xuyen
    if (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 < 7 ^ 2) and (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 > 0 ^ 2)
    [
     set pcolor blue
    ]
    ;;;; tao duong phan van tri
    
  
    if  abs (pxcor) > 0 and abs (pxcor) < 7 and (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 > 10 ^ 2)
    [
     set pcolor grey
    ]
   
        ;;;tao giai phan cach giua duong pham van dong
    if abs (pycor) >= 0 and abs (pycor) <= 1.5 and (abs (pxcor) > 35)
    [
     set pcolor yellow
     ]
    ;;;tao lan oto duong pham van dong
    if abs (pycor) > 1.5 and abs (pycor) < 17 and (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 > 10 ^ 2)
    [
     set pcolor grey
     ]
    ;;tao dai phan cach lan xe may duong pham van dong
     if abs (pycor) >= 17 and abs (pycor) <= 19 and (abs (pxcor) > 35)
    [
     set pcolor yellow
    ]
    
    ;;;tao lan xe may duong pham van dong
     if abs (pycor) > 19 and abs (pycor) < 26 and (pxcor ^ 2 + pycor ^ 2 > 10 ^ 2)
    [
     set pcolor grey
    ]
    ;;;tao lan duong re phai pham van dong - phan van tri và phan van tri-pham van dong phia ben duoi
    if ((abs (pxcor) - 55 < pycor) and (abs (pxcor) - 35 > pycor) and  abs (pxcor) > -10 and pycor < -10)
    [
     set pcolor grey
    ]
     ;;;tao lan duong re phai pham van dong - phan van tri phia ben tren
    if (( (- pxcor) + 55 > pycor) and ( (- pxcor) + 35 < pycor) and (pxcor) > 0 and pycor > 10)
    [
     set pcolor grey
    ]
    ;;;tao lan duong re phai phan van tri - pham van dong phia ben tren
    if (( ( pxcor) + 55 > pycor) and ( ( pxcor) + 35 < pycor) and (pxcor) < 0 and pycor > 10)
    [
     set pcolor grey
     ]
    
    
]  
reset-ticks
end


;;;phan phoi xe oto
to distribute-cars 
  set heading random 4 * 90
  ;;lan phan van tri ben phai
  if (heading = 0)
  [setxy (1 + random(pxcor + 6)) (40 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)]
   
   
  ;;lan phan van tri ben trai 
  if (heading = 180)
  [setxy (-1 + random(pxcor - 6)) ((40 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1))]
    ;;lan pham van dong ben duoi
   
    if (heading = 90)
    [setxy ((40 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (-3 + random(pycor - 13 ))]
    
  ;;;lan pham van dong ben tren
     
    if (heading = 270)
      [setxy ((40 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (3 + random(pycor + 13 ))]
   
  if any? other turtles-here
  [distribute-cars ]
end

;;;phan phoi xe may
to distribute-motos
  set heading random 4 * 90
  ;;;lan phan van tri ben phai
  if (heading = 0)
 [setxy (1 + random(pycor + 6)) (40 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)]
  
 
   ;;lan pham van dong ben duoi
    if (heading = 90)
    [setxy ((40 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (-20 + random(pycor - 6 ))]
  
  
  ;;lan phan van tri ben trai 
  if (heading = 180)
  [setxy (-1 + random(pycor - 6)) ((40 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1))]
  
  ;;;lan pham van dong ben tren
  if (heading = 270)
      [setxy ((40 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (20 + random(pycor + 6 ))]
 
    
  if any? other turtles-here
  [distribute-motos ]
end
;;;phan phoi xe tai
to distribute-truck 
  set heading random 4 * 90
  ;;lan phan van tri ben phai
  if (heading = 0)
  [setxy (1 + random(pxcor + 6)) (60 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)]
   
   
  ;;lan phan van tri ben trai 
  if (heading = 180)
  [setxy (-1 + random(pxcor - 6)) ((60 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1))]
    ;;lan pham van dong ben duoi
   
    if (heading = 90)
    [setxy ((60 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (-3 + random(pycor - 13 ))]
    
  ;;;lan pham van dong ben tren
     
    if (heading = 270)
      [setxy ((60 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (3 + random(pycor + 13 ))]
  if any? other turtles-here
  [distribute-truck ]
end
;;;phan phoi xe buyt
to distribute-bus 
set heading random 4 * 90
  ;;lan phan van tri ben phai
  if (heading = 0)
  [setxy (1 + random(pxcor + 6)) (60 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)]
   
   
  ;;lan phan van tri ben trai 
  if (heading = 180)
  [setxy (-1 + random(pxcor - 6)) ((60 + random (max-pycor - 30)) * (2 * random 2 - 1))]
    ;;lan pham van dong ben duoi
   
    if (heading = 90)
    [setxy ((60 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (-3 + random(pycor - 13 ))]
    
  ;;;lan pham van dong ben tren
     
    if (heading = 270)
      [setxy ((60 + random (max-pxcor - 38)) * (2 * random 2 - 1)) (3 + random(pycor + 13 ))]
  if any? other turtles-here
  [distribute-bus ]
end

to go
ask cartop [goallcar]
ask mototopview [goallmoto]
ask trucktopview [goalltruck]
ask bustopview [goallbus]
  tick
  if ticks > 30000 [stop]
end 


to goallcar
  let myhd heading
 set headingdirection (subtract-headings myhd (towardsxy 0 0))
ifelse color = red and distancexy 0 0 < 31.7
[
goright
]
[
ifelse distancexy 0 0 <= 15
[
gostraightleft
]
[
gomainroad
]
]
plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280 ; convert from feet per tick to mph
end
to goright
; if [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 23 != grey

 
if headingdirection > 0 and headingdirection < 40 ; begin right turn
[
set gl_cars-count gl_cars-count + 1
set droundabout 0
;;;rt 45


if heading = 90 
[ 
  ;; ask cars
  if distancexy 0 0 = -55 and distancexy 0 0 = 55
  [
   
    rt 50
    if pycor = -20
    [ 
      rt 90
    ]
  ]   
    
]
rt 45    
]  



ifelse droundabout < gl_distance-right 
[
let myhd heading
let d gl_distance-right - droundabout
ifelse d > 12
[
let t d / speed 
let cars-45degrees cartop with [(subtract-headings heading myhd = 45) and (distance myself < 52.35)]
let cars-ininterval cars-45degrees with [(distancexy 0 0) + speed * t > 15 and (distancexy 0 0) + 
speed * t < 46.39]
ifelse any? cars-ininterval
[
let deceleration-to-stop (speed ^ 2 / (2 * (d - 12)))
set speed speed - deceleration-to-stop
]
[
set speed speed + gl_accelerator
]
] 
[
set speed speed + gl_accelerator
]
if (speed > gl_speed-maxright) [set speed gl_speed-maxright]
if (speed < gl_speed-min) [set speed gl_speed-min]
; plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280 ; convert from feet per tick to mph
fd speed
set droundabout droundabout + speed
]
[ 
; plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280; convert from feet per tick to mph
rt 45
fd speed
set droundabout 0
readjustcordinate
]
    
end
to gostraightleft
; if [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 5 != grey
if droundabout = 0 ; begin roundabout left turn or go straight
[
set gl_cars-count gl_cars-count + 1
set speed gl_speed-maxcircle
set droundabout 0.00001 ; start roundabout
rt 66.422
]
ifelse ((color = sky and droundabout < gl_distance-left ) or (color = green and droundabout < 
gl_distance-straight ))
[
let carsinroundabout other cartop with [distancexy 0 0 < 15]
fd speed
lt speed * gl_degree-per-foot
set droundabout droundabout + speed
let d distancexy 0 0 / 14.9999
setxy (xcor / d) (ycor / d) 
]
[ 
; plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280; convert from feet per tick to mph
rt 66.422
fd speed
set droundabout 0
readjustcordinate
]
end
to gomainroad
let myhd heading
let dfromcenter (distancexy 0 0)
let speed1 speed; save the initial speed for later use
if ( dfromcenter > 15)
[ 
let dseparation gl_carminseparation + speed * gl_reactiontime 
let cars-same-direction other cartop with [heading = myhd]
ifelse any? cars-same-direction
[
let cars-ahead other cars-same-direction with [(distance myself) != 0 and (towards myself) != myhd]
ifelse any? cars-ahead
[
let car-nearest (min-one-of cars-ahead [distance myself])
let dtocar-nearest distance car-nearest
let vofcar-nearest [speed] of car-nearest
ifelse dtocar-nearest < dseparation
[
if speed >= vofcar-nearest 
[
set speed speed - gl_decelerator 
]
if dtocar-nearest < gl_carminseparation
[ 
set speed speed - gl_decelerator
if speed >= vofcar-nearest 
[ set speed vofcar-nearest - gl_decelerator ]
]
]
[ set speed speed + gl_accelerator ] ; end car-nearest
]
[ set speed speed + gl_accelerator ] ; end cars-ahead
]
[ set speed speed + gl_accelerator ] ; end cars-same-direction
] ; end distancexy 0 0
; if ( (distancexy 0 0) > 15 and (distancexy 0 0) < 16.7)
; [ 
; let cars-45degree cars with [(subtract-headings heading myhd = -45) ]
; ]
if ( dfromcenter > 25 and dfromcenter < 50 )
[ 
let d dfromcenter - 25 
let t d / speed
let cars-inroundabout cartop with [(distancexy 0 0) <= 15]
let cars-ininterval cars-inroundabout with [(subtract-headings heading myhd > 0 )]
if any? cars-ininterval
[ 
let deceleration-to-stop (speed ^ 2 / (2 * d))
set speed speed - deceleration-to-stop
]
]
let vmax gl_speed-max
if (dfromcenter < gl_distanceto00)
[
let speed2 speed; save the just calculated speed
set speed speed1; restore the initial speed
ifelse color = red
[
let d sqrt ( dfromcenter ^ 2 - 36) - 31 + gl_distance-right
let t d / speed
let cars-perpendicular cartop with [(subtract-headings heading myhd = 90) and (subtract-headings 
(towards myself) myhd < 0)]
let cars-ininterval cars-perpendicular with [(distancexy 0 0) + speed * t > 15 and (distancexy 0 0) + 
speed * t < 46.39]
ifelse any? cars-ininterval
[
let deceleration-to-stop (speed ^ 2 / (2 * (d - 12)))
set speed speed - deceleration-to-stop
]
[
set speed speed + gl_accelerator
]
if (speed > speed2) [set speed speed2]
]
[
set speed speed2
]
let dfromcircle sqrt(dfromcenter ^ 2 - 36) - gl_side ; gl_side = sqrt(15^2+6^2)
set vmax sqrt(gl_speed-max ^ 2 - 2 * gl_decelerator * (gl_slowdown - dfromcircle)) ; gl_slowdown = (v^2 - v0^2)/(2a)
]
if vmax > gl_speed-max 
[ 
set vmax gl_speed-max 
]
if speed > vmax 
[
set speed vmax
]
if speed < gl_speed-min
[
set speed gl_speed-min 
] 
forward speed
end



;;;;;chay xe moto
to goallmoto
let myhd heading
set headingdirection (subtract-headings myhd (towardsxy 0 0))
ifelse color = red and distancexy 0 0 < 31.7
[
goright
]
[
ifelse distancexy 0 0 <= 15
[
gostraightleft
]
[
gomainroad
]
]
plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280 ; convert from feet per tick to mph
end


;;;chay xe truck
to goalltruck
let myhd heading
set headingdirection (subtract-headings myhd (towardsxy 0 0))
ifelse color = red and distancexy 0 0 < 31.7
[
goright
]
[
ifelse distancexy 0 0 <= 15
[
gostraightleft
]
[
gomainroad
]
]
plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280 ; convert from feet per tick to mph
end


;;;chay xe bus
to goallbus
let myhd heading
set headingdirection (subtract-headings myhd (towardsxy 0 0))
ifelse color = red and distancexy 0 0 < 31.7
[
goright
]
[
ifelse distancexy 0 0 <= 15
[
gostraightleft
]
[
gomainroad
]
]
plot [speed] of gl_my-car * 360000 / 5280 ; convert from feet per tick to mph
end

to chuyenlan
  distribute-cars 
 goallcar
   ;;;if heading = 0 and color = red
  ;;;[
   ;; if 
   ;;rt 45
  ;; if (xcor = -10)
  ;;  ]
    ;;if any? other turtles-here
 ;; [chuyenlan ]
 ;; ]
end

to readjustcordinate
if (heading > 355 or heading < 5)
[
set heading 0
set xcor 6
]
if (heading > 85 and heading < 95)
[
set heading 90
set ycor -6
]
if (heading > 175 and heading < 185)
[
set heading 180
set xcor -6
]
if (heading > 265 and heading < 275)
[
set heading 270
set ycor 6
]
end
```

]

[![1]

how to write Algorithms running cars. 3-lane road. cheap car left lane 1 and lane 2 car go straight, lanes 3 cheap car right. tạo random initial car. (Low red car on the right, go straight green, sky swerved left). to 1 position if the car red là có all moved to the right lane for cheap car. green car vehicle moving straight to go straight lane, sky car move to the left lane cheap.

revise section drive algorithm. because it runs false

[1]]

how to write Algorithms running cars. 3-lane road. cheap car left lane 1 and lane 2 car go straight, lanes 3 cheap car right. tạo random initial car. (Low red car on the right, go straight green, sky swerved left). to 1 position if the car red là có all moved to the right lane for cheap car. green car vehicle moving straight to go straight lane, sky car move to the left lane cheap.

revise section drive algorithm. because it runs false

[1]

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59IAs.jpg

Comment: in is unclear to me what the exact question is maybe break it down into multiple questions?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what your question is.

Comment: I want to add right turn lane as vehicles for regulation lies with large horizontal lines as shown

Comment: It might be easier for us if you constructed a minimum working example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Just have one type of vehicle that is trying to do the right turn.

Comment: A good question is specific. You can't just give us a lot of code and a broad statement of what you're trying to do and expect us to fill in the rest. Where exactly are you stuck with this?